# Regular Expression Matching all permutations

Tags: regex

I want to find all the permutations of 0123 in the string below
01210210021212333212300213231102023103130001332121230221000012333333021032112

can i have a regular expression that can give me the permutations of 0123 matching in the string ?
Also i need if there are any overlapped patters

"0123" here i want a match of [1023][1230][2301][3012]

Comment: 1234 or 0123? :P Also the permutations of 0123 are many more than what you posted e.g. [3102][1302]...

Comment: Also are you sure you mean permutations?...

Comment: What language are you using ? What have you tried ?

Comment: If you can verify what you actually want with one totally unambiguous example - I, or someone else, will resolve (or indicate if impossible).

Comment: What you've given in your example are rotations of "0123" not permutations. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not regex, but C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s("01210210021212333212300213231102023103130001332121230221000012333333021032112");
    const std::string ref("0123");

    if(ref.length() > s.length())
    {
        return 0;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length() - ref.length(); ++i)
    {
        if(std::is_permutation(s.cbegin()+i, s.cbegin()+i+ref.length(), ref.cbegin()))
        {
            const std::string extract(s, i, ref.length());
            std::cout << extract << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To be compiled for example with `g++ -std=c++11 -o sample sample.cpp`

If you absolutely need regex: `(?=[0123]{3})(.)(?!\1)(.)(?!\1|\2)(.)(?!\1|\2|\3).` which means:

```
(?=[0123]{3}) : positive assertion that the 4 next characters are 0, 1, 2, 3
(.) : capture first character
(?!\1) : assert that following character is not the first capture group
(.) : capture second character
(?!\1|\2) : assert that following character is neither the first nor the second capture group
etc.
```

Comment: Your [regex](http://regex101.com/r/rM2yE6) doesn't take in account overlapped matches.

Comment: @HamZa, correct. And the C++ code does. However I don't know which behaviour OP wants.

Comment: I've come up with a solution by contructing the regex dynamically. Check the final [regex online](http://regex101.com/r/qJ1yU6)

Comment: @HamZa, post this as an answer!

Comment: Heh, I can't. I mean I voted to close the question, so it's a bit awkward to answer it. Also if I'm constructing the regex dynamically, then I might just use a pure non-regex solution. Note that your regex will work if you put it in a loop and truncate a character in each loop if you get what I mean :)

Answer (score 0):

A regular expression cannot do what you're asking for. It cannot generate permutations from a string.