# Regex with limited use of specific characters (like a scrabble bank of letters)

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to be able to do a regex where I can identify sort of a bank of letters like `[dgos]` for example and use that within my regex... but whenever a letter from that gets used, it takes it away from the bank.

So lets say that somehow `\1` is able to stand for that bank of letters (`dgos`). I could write a regex something like:

```
^\1{1}o\1{2}$
```

and it would match basically:
`\1{1}` = `[dgos]{1}`
`o`
`\1{2}` = `[dgos]{2}` minus whatever was used in the first one

Matches could include `good`, `dosg`, `sogd`, etc... and would not include `sods` (because `s` would have to be used twice) or `sooo` (because the `o` would have to be used twice).

I would also like to be able to identify letters that can be used more than once. I started to write this myself but then realized I didn't even know where to begin with this so I've also searched around and haven't found a very elegant way to do this, or a way to do it that would be **flexible enough that the regex could easily be generated with minimal input.**

I have a solution below using a combination of conditions and multiple regexs (feel free to comment thoughts on that answer - perhaps it's the way I'll have to do it?), but I would prefer a single regex solution if possible... and something more elegant and efficient if possible.

Note that the higher level of elegance and single regex part are just my preferences, the most important thing is that it works and the performance is good enough.

Comment: Although I don't have time to really contemplate this now, I think you might have the makings of a fascinating question here.  Your solution below is mixed up though.  You really need to present a solution that separates out the actual API you're looking for from the test code wrapping around it.  I also think you need to think carefully through the API you're looking for.  Almost certainly it cannot be done with normal regex, so you want some sort of extended regex.  Can you find a notation that make it clear what you want but that still makes sense with other regex conventions?

Comment: I understand that you have the start of a convention here, but there is no clear way the your banks of letters are applied to `\1`, or am I missing something?

Comment: @ScottSauyet, that part was just assumed. I was just showing that as an example of what would be nice to have.

Comment: I suppose if I were to create a convention it would look **something like** `^(?#1,dgos){1}o\1{2}$` where `(?#1,dgos)` both creates and uses the "bank" of letters and then it gets used again with `\1`  (although I don't know if this conflicts with something - it probably does)

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17722146) ?

Comment: Are you looking for this to be general enough to handle `\2`, `\3`, etc., or is `\1` all you'll ever need?

Comment: @HamZa, sort of but not really. It is much more limiting than what I am looking for.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, in my case, I'd only ever need one bank of letters.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using javascript version 1.5+ (so you can use lookaheads), here is my solution:

```
^([dogs])(?!.*\1)([dogs])(?!.*\2)([dogs])(?!.*\3)[dogs]$
```

So after each letter is matched, you perform a negative lookahead to ensure that this matched letter never appears again.

This method wouldn't work (or at least, would need to be made a heck of a lot more complicated!) if you want to allow some letters to be repeated, however. (E.g. if your letters to match are "example".)

EDIT: I just had a little re-think, and here is a much more elegant solution:

```
^(?:([dogs])(?!.*\1)){4}
```

Comment: From the OP: "I would also like to be able to identify letters that can be used more than once."  This is elegant, yes, but I don't think it gets the job done.

Comment: Aye... However, I doubt that's even possible with regex alone. At the very least, I think, you'd need to specify a list of which letters can appear once, twice, three times, etc (WITH A FINITE LIMIT! - i.e. The regex would have a hardcoded limitation). I could then come up with some really ugly regex to solve that problem...

Comment: Yea, if I'm not able to find for multiple of a specific letter I might as well not have a solution at all. Also, could this work for the example in my question where the bank of letters needs to be filled around a specific letter? I'm not familiar with the `\1` syntax that you are using, could you expand and explain that regex?

Comment: \1 means "the first capture group" - i.e. Whatever was matched in the  brackets. By putting "?:" at the start of the brackets, you make it a non-capture group. So basically what's matched in ([dogs]) (i.e. one letter at a time) is equal to "\1". The variable gets over-written each time, so at the end of the match, it will be equal to the last letter of the matched word.

Comment: And going back to my first attempt at a solution, let's say you require the third letter to be an "o". Then you can use: ^([dogs])(?!.*\1)([dogs])(?!.*\2)o(?!.*o)[dogs]$ (And can probably make that a bit tidier/more generalised like I did below, too.)

Answer (score 1):

After thinking about it some more, I have thought of a way that this IS possible, although this solution is pretty ugly! For example, suppose you want to match the letters "goods" (i.e. including TWO "o"s):

```
 ^(?=.*g)(?=.*o.*o)(?=.*d)(?=.*s).{5}$
```

- So, I have used forward lookaheads to check that all of these letters are in the text somewhere, then simply checked that there are exactly 5 letters.

Or as another example, suppose we want to match the letters "banana", with a letter "a" in position 2 of the word. Then you could match:

```
 ^(?=.*b)(?=.*a.*a.*a)(?=.*n.*n).a.{4}$
```

Comment: This is interesting.  But I'm not quite sure how it matches the original problem.  Are you proposing a pre-expansion of all possible character classes into a monstrous regex joined by `|`?  If not, how would this help with, say, `^(?#1,dgos){1}o\1{2}$` ?

Comment: That should match "dogo", "dogs", "doog", "doos", "dosg", "doso", "godo", "gods", "good", "goos", "gosd", "goso", "oodg", "oogd", "oods", "oosd", "oogs", "oosg", "sodg", "sodo", "sogd", "sogo", "sood", or "soog" (and I've probably missed some.)

Comment: Erm...Have you commented on the wrong answer? My solution doesn't require any pre-expansion or use of "|".

Comment: Also, is the syntax "(?#1,...)" even valid?! What the heck does it mean? I thought that was only given as a sort of pseudocode to try to explain a possible solution!

Comment: This is actually pretty interesting and seems to work well for several situations... however, in trying to follow your pattern, I am unable to get it to match a case where it is like `D(2 letters from bank)R(more letters from bank)`. See second scenario here: http://jsfiddle.net/T2TMd/4/

Comment: Well now you've changed the problem completely - namely, because you're not requiring all letters from the bank to be used! Hence, the forward lookaheads (which require ALL letters in the bank to be present) are causing the test to fail.

Comment: But, how about this: ^(?!.*o.*o)(?!.*a.*a)(?!.*e.*e.*e)(?!.*s.*s)d[oaes]{2}r[oaes]{0,3}$

Comment: I've changed it so you're now "not allowed too many" of each letter (as opposed to being required a certain number of each letter), and also each of the (letters from bank) parts must explicitly only contain letters from the bank, rather than it being required implicitly by the positive lookaheads.

Comment: @TomLord, The problem hasn't been changed at all - I've never required all letters to be used. If I did... my example in my question would not make sense as I had 4 letters in the bank and gave 3 positions for the bank to be used. The solution in your comment works for this scenario. I don't have the time at the moment to play around with this to see if it can work with all the scenarios that I can foresee and create an interface for it so the regexes can be generated from a simpler interface and see how fast in performs in comparison, but hopefully later today I'll get a chance.

Comment: The problem hasn't changed at all? The example you have was with a bank: (dgos), and possible matches: "dosg", "sogd" and "good" (which isn't even a match, so your original example was wrong!). You never mentioned using *some* of the letters from the bank, until now. Anyway, never mind... The solution I gave in the comment above will work for any scenario like that. Unless you want to complicate it even further in some way - e.g. if you want to search for matches of (some bank letters)ABCD(some more bank letters), where there can be repeated bank letters between those groups.

Comment: @TomLord, I think you misread the original example. It says the bank was "dgos" and I'm pulling 1 letter from the bank, then there is a fixed "o", then I am pulling 2 more letters from the bank. In all, there are 3 letters I'm pulling from the bank and a fixed "o" in the second position of the string. "good" would in fact be a match because "g" gets pulled from the bank (now the bank has "dos"), then there is a fixed "o", then an "o" is pulled from the bank (bank is now "ds"), then the "d" is pulled from the bank. As far as the 'complicate it further' case, I am looking for flexibility.

Comment: An example of complexity (or the flexibility to deal with it), try going [here](http://smerny.site88.net/testDictionarySearch.html) and entering `D,<2>,RK,<1>,O,<0-2>` with a letter bank of `OOBNEES`. This uses multiple fixed characters and multiple areas where I can pull from the letter bank (including both fixed and variable number of characters to pull for those groups)

Comment: Ahh ok, I see it now. Sorry, I misinterpreted that first example due to your slightly confusing choice of letters. (And my own laziness, probably.) But anyway, that example you just linked isn't really complicating it any further than you did previously -- I've already solved that problem.

Comment: Okay, then could you explain "if you want to search for matches of (some bank letters)ABCD(some more bank letters), where there can be repeated bank letters between those groups". I think I misunderstand because it seems to be the same situation to me as what I would write in the builder as `<0-7>,ABCD,<0-7>` which actually seems like a simpler scenario than `D,<2>,RK,<1>,O,<0-2>`

Comment: Sorry, been away from this for some hours.  @TomLord: does @smerny's clarifications of the problem answer your questions about my objections?  `^(?#1,dgos){1}o\1{2}$` was shorthand for something like "One letter from the bank, followed by an 'o', followed by two distinct letters from the now reduced bank, where the bank consists of one copy each of 'd', 'g', 'o', and 's'."

Comment: @smerny If you don't want to allow repeated bank letters (i.e. the letter bank does not get "reset" after each group), then I have already solved the problem. But for instance, suppose your bank is "WXYZ", your pattern is <0-4>ABC<0-4> and you want to allow "WXYABCXYZ" as a valid match. This is what I was talking about as an example of "extending the problem further", and my answer above doesn't quite cover that scenario.

Comment: @TomLord, okay, I do not want `WXYABCXYZ` as a valid match so no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

Building on @TomLord's answer, taking into account that you don't necessarily need to exhaust the bank of letters, you can use [negative lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of positive ones. For your example `D<2 from bank>R<0-5 from bank>`, that regex would be

```
/^(?![^o]*o[^o]*o)(?![^a]*a[^a]*a)(?![^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*e)(?![^s]*s[^s]*s)d[oaes]{2}r[oaes]{0,5}$/i
```

**Explanation:**

```
^                        # Start of string
(?![^o]*o[^o]*o)         # Assert no more than one o
(?![^a]*a[^a]*a)         # Assert no more than one a
(?![^e]*e[^e]*e[^e]*e)   # Assert no more than two e
(?![^s]*s[^s]*s)         # Assert no more than one s
d                        # Match d
[oaes]{2}                # Match two of the letters in the bank
r                        # Match r
[oaes]{0,5}              # Match 0-5 of the letters in the bank
$                        # End of string
```

You could also write `(?!.*o.*o)` instead of `(?![^o]*o[^o]*o)`, but the latter is faster, just harder to read. Another way to write this is `(?!(?:[^o]*o){2})` (useful if the number of repetitions increases).

And of course you need to account for the number of letters in your "fixed" part of the string (which in this case (`d` and `r`) don't interfere with the bank, but they might do so in other examples).

Comment: This is pretty impressive and I appreciate the effort, but as you said it is limited in that the fixed parts cannot contain letters that are in the word bank: http://jsfiddle.net/T2TMd/6/. Also I don't really mind readability as long as the regex can be easily generated - then I can just create a more user friendly interface for it.

Comment: I normally consider myself pretty decent with regex, but I am sort of baffled by this. How do 2 pairs of `[^o]*o` limit to a single `o` while 3 pairs would limit to two (I also just tested and 4 pairs limits to three). My head hurts a bit thinking about it.

Comment: @smerny: Oh, the fixed parts can contain letters that are in the bank, you just need to account for them in the lookahead assertions. Those simply check that it's impossible to match what's in them, so if `[^o]*o[^o]*o` matches we know that there's more than one `o` in the string etc.

Comment: `+1` You're right, it seems that I can account for the fixed parts by including them into the word bank as well: http://jsfiddle.net/T2TMd/8/ . I'll have to play around with this later and see if I can get something to work with it and how it compares in performance to my original solution.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't think of a way to do this completely in a regex, but I was able to come up with this: http://jsfiddle.net/T2TMd/2/

As jsfiddle is limited to post size, I couldn't do the larger dictionary there. [Check here](http://smerny.site88.net/testDictionarySearch.html) for a better example using a 180k word dictionary.

Main function:

```
/*
* filter = regex to filter/split potential matches
* bank = available letters
* groups = capture groups that use the bank
* dict = list of words to search through
*/
var matchFind = function(filter, bank, groups, dict) {
    var matches = [];
    for(var i=0; i < dict.length; i++) {
        if(dict[i].match(filter)){
            var fail = false;
            var b = bank;
            var arr = dict[i].split(filter);
            //loop groups that use letter bank
            for(var k=0; k<groups.length && !fail; k++) {
                var grp = arr[groups[k]] || [];
                //loop characters of that group
                for(var j=0; j<grp.length && !fail; j++) {
                    var regex = new RegExp(b);
                    var currChar = grp.charAt(j);
                    if(currChar.match(regex)) {
                        //match found, remove from bank
                        b = b.replace(currChar,"");
                    } else { 
                        fail = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!fail) {
                matches.push(dict[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

Usage:

```
$("#go").click( function() {
    var f = new RegExp($("#filter").val());
    var b = "["+$("#bank").val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g,"").toUpperCase()+"]";
    var g = $("#groups").val().replace(/[^0-9,]+/g,"").split(",") || [];
    $("#result").text(matchFind(f,b,g,dict).toString());
});
```

To make it easier to create scenarios, I created this as well:

```
$("#build").click( function() {
    var bank = "["+$("#buildBank").val().replace(/[^A-Za-z]+/g,"").toUpperCase()+"]";
    var buildArr = $("#builder").val().split(",");
    var groups = [];
    var build = "^";
    for(var i=0; i<buildArr.length; i++) {
        var part = buildArr[i];
        if(/\</.test(part)) {
            part = "(" + bank + part.replace("<", "{").replace(">", "}").replace("-",",") + ")";
            build = build + part;
            groups.push(i+1);
        } else {
            build = build + "("+part+")";
        }
    }
    build = build + "$";
    $("#filter").val(build);
    $("#bank").val(bank);
    $("#groups").val(groups.toString());
    $("#go").click();
});
```

This would be useful in Scrabble, so lets say that you are in a position where a word must start with a "D", there are two spaces between that "D" and an "R" from a parallel word, and you have `OAEES` for your letter bank. In the builder I could put `D,<2>,R,<0-3>` because it must start with a D, then it must have 2 letters from the bank, then there is an R, then I'd have up to 3 letters to use (since I'm using 2 in between D and R).

The builder would use the letter bank and convert `D,<2>,R,<0-3>` to `^(D)([OAEES]{2})(R)([OAEES]{0,5})$` which would be used to filter for possible matches. Then with those possible matches it will look at the capture groups that use the letter bank, character by character, removing letters from that regex when it finds them so that it won't match if there are more of the letter bank letters used than there is in the letter bank.

Test the above scenario [here](http://smerny.site88.net/testDictionarySearch.html).

Comment: Please post thoughts here... especially if you down-voted. I'm starting to wonder if this (or something like it) is the best way as it is very flexible and the filter should remove a lot of the unnecessary processing.

Comment: Changed it up a little and tested with a 180k word dictionary and it seems to be working well... [sample here](http://smerny.site88.net/testDictionarySearch.html)

Comment: (I didn't downvote, but...) Whilst I agree that something like this is a much more sensible solution than pure regex, you didn't actually address the question (/challenge?) of doing it that way. Also, to be honest, the code doesn't exactly look elegant to me...

Comment: Actually, the question is specifically asking if there is a more elegant and more regex focused way of doing this than my current solution. Of course my current solution doesn't address being more than what it itself is, but that seems like an odd thing to point out. Also, I said would prefer a more elegant solution... my first concern is functionality. This is pretty functional in that it does everything that I need it to and does it quickly enough... I'm just curious if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that would be pretty simple to specify, just very long

```
gdos|gdso|gods|gosd|....
```

You'd basically specify every permutation. Just write some code to generate every permutation, combine with the alternate operator, and you're done!

Although... It might pay to actually encode the decision tree used to generate the permutations...

I swear I think I answered this before on stackoverflow.  Let me get back to you...

Comment: [demo](http://regex101.com/r/qJ1yU6) in case of `1234` matching even overlapped sequences :)

Comment: So suppose you wanted to do this with a 10 letter word... That means you'd have 2^10=1024 permutations, which means your regex would be 1024*11 - 1 = 11264 characters long. Ouch!

Comment: @TomLord... yes, it is too much. Also, how would this work for if I want [gdos] letter bank to be able to be used around a specific letter? Like I want to make sure the third letter is "t"? I'd have to factor that into all the permutations.

Comment: I think some variant of this just might be necessary, though.  At least I can think of no straightforward way to *use* regular expressions to do this.  Perhaps someone knows enough about how to *extend* them to handle this sort of case.  I would not do this manually of course; a helper function to do this doesn't sound terribly difficult.

Comment: (By comparison, my answer - although admittedly it would not be able to handle repeating letters, whereas yours would - would require no calculation of permutations and the regex would be 31 characters long.)