# Javascript regex to solve fill in the words

Tags: javascript, django, regex

I'm looking for a way to solve hangman puzzles automatically.

Let's say my input is ___o_ and I have a word bank of "llaory" just to make it easy.

I'll look through a big list of all english words and use a regex to search for anything that matches.

What I have so far that works is this.

```
import raw from "./static/wordlist.txt";
let reg = new RegExp(
 "\\b" +
    letters.replace(
      /_/g,
      `[${bank}]`
    ) +
    "\\b",

  "g"
);
fetch(raw)
  .then((r) => r.text())
  .then((text) => {
    if (text.match(reg)) {
      console.log(text.match(reg));
    }
  });
```

Bank is the word bank so in this case it is llaory.

The results from this are 2 words ['alloy', 'alloo'].

The correct and only option should be alloy but alloo is an option because the code can't recognize that only 1 o can be used.

How can I make it so that the regex knows that letters can only be used as much as there are in the bank?

I've seen this post [Regex with limited use of specific characters (like a scrabble bank of letters)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17791858/regex-with-limited-use-of-specific-characters-like-a-scrabble-bank-of-letters) but it doesn't seem to work when there is a letter already present as shown with the ___o_

Comment: I removed the java tag. Java and JavaScript are two different languages (very different), so I could not see its relevance here. As user SuperNova said once on Discord: “Similar name, totally different things. the things that they share are that everyone hates them and they are used everywhere.” :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the words that have the exact length as the hangman word and where [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) character matches the hangman word.

There's also a `knownChars` [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) that stores all the characters in our hangman word. Using this set we ensure that the `_` characters in our hangman word correspond to only those characters which are *not* present in the `knownChars` set.

In the example below, the word `london` is *not* present in the `filteredWords` array because the second last character in the hangman word is a `_` which corresponds the character `o` which is already present in the `knownChars` set, hence `london` isn't a valid choice.

```js
const 
  wordlist = ["monkey", "donkey", "moon", "donut", "london"],
  word = "_on___",
  knownChars = new Set(Array.prototype.filter.call(word, (ch) => ch !== "_")),
  filteredWords = wordlist.filter(
    (w) =>
      w.length === word.length &&
      Array.prototype.every.call(
        word,
        (ch, i) => (ch === "_" && !knownChars.has(w[i])) || ch === w[i]
      )
  );

console.log(filteredWords);
```

**Note:** Methods like `Array.prototype.every` and `Array.prototype.filter` are generic methods, so they can be used with strings as well.

**Tip:** If you find `Array.prototype.every.call` a little verbose, then you can also do `[].every.call`.

Comment: But what about the implementation that you can't use a letter more than once unless there is more than 1 letter in the word bank?

Comment: @JamesHuang So, you mean in my example something like `london` would be in the resultant array but actually it shouldn't because `o` is already discovered and if `london` was valid then it would have revealed the second last `o` as well. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @JamesHuang I've updated my answer to tackle that scenario as well, have a look.

Comment: I think what your code does is prevent characters from being reused more than once. What I'm more thinking of is not entirely like hangman. In the original question, I mentioned the use of a letter bank "llaory" which specifies which letters can be used and how many times. L can be used twice but only since there are 2 L's in the bank